# TextField truncation with ellipsis

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, textfield

I have a single line `TextField`, and I'm looking to truncate excess text with an ellipsis (`...`) at the end.

I tried to use the `truncationMode` API, but it doesn't work at all, and it also completely messes up the `TextField` selection.

Here is the code to reproduce the problem on a brand new plain SwiftUI MacOS project: (running **Monterey RC 1, Xcode 13.1 RC 1**):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = ""
    @State var text2 = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Sidebar")
            TextField("Placeholder", text: $text)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .truncationMode(.tail)
            TextField("Click on me to lose focus", text: $text2)
                .frame(width: 100)
        }
    }
}
```

Run the app, and then type a bunch of text into the big text box. You should observe no trimming but also erratic behavior in the text box's selection.

I tried using a `NSTextField` with `NSViewRepresentable`, and it worked great, except for the fact that I'm also trying to center the text.

When the text is centered and `NSTextField.lineBreakMode` is set, then the cursor doesn't go to the right place when the placeholder is visible.

I was wondering if anybody is able to reproduce this issue, and, if so, are there any solutions?

Comment: it seems to work as expected for me on macos 12.01, xcode 13.1(RC), target ios 15 and macCatalyst. Although I included a `VStack {...}` 
to enclose the `Text` and `TextFields`.

Comment: @workingdog Ah, I was just using a plain SwiftUI project. That explains it. Thanks for testing it though!

Comment: does not seem to work on _macOS 13.1 (22C65)_ even with `VStack`

Answer (score 1):

With macOS 13 Ventura you have to set the axis in order to make the TextField truncate. The axis are used to determine in which direction to scroll text when it doesn’t fit in the available space unless you set truncation modifier.

```
TextField("Placeholder", text: $text, axis: .vertical) // <- 1. use axis
    .truncationMode(.tail)  <- 2. set the truncationMode
```